# Lower bandwidth on Linux than on Windows behind same wireless router

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, bandwidth

**UPDATE:**  *When I connected via an Ethernet cable directly running from my Linux laptop to my wireless router, I get the correct bandwdith (~10 Mbits/s).  It's only when I connect wirelessly that my bandwidth is so small as described below.*

---

I have two laptops with roughly the same specs.  One is running Windows 7, the other is running Ubuntu 12.04.  When I run a speed test at http://testmy.net, the Linux laptop pulls approximately **1 Mbits/s**, whereas the Windows laptop pulls approximately **10 Mbits/s**.  Running speed test on other speed-test providers yields similar differences in downstream bandwidth between the two laptops: the Linux laptop is consistently much slower.

Trying to exercise due diligence, I also tested the Linux laptop's bandwidth using `iperf`.  The `iperf` server is on a Linux desktop computer (which I use exclusively) in my office at a major university in the UNC system.  To run the server, I entered the command

```
# iperf -s -p 9090 -w 1024k -l 100k
```

and, on my Linux laptop at home (behind an AT&T U-Verse router), I ran the iperf client (test) by entering the command

```
$ iperf -i 2 -p 9090 -c XX.XX.XX.XX -t 50 -w 1024k -l 100k
```

The output from the test was

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to XX.XX.XX.XX, TCP port 9090
TCP window size:  256 KByte (WARNING: requested 1.00 MByte)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 192.168.1.69 port 43880 connected with XX.XX.XX.XX port 9090
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 2.0 sec   400 KBytes  1.64 Mbits/sec
[  3]  2.0- 4.0 sec   400 KBytes  1.64 Mbits/sec
[  3]  4.0- 6.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3]  6.0- 8.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3]  8.0-10.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3] 10.0-12.0 sec   400 KBytes  1.64 Mbits/sec
[  3] 12.0-14.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3] 14.0-16.0 sec   400 KBytes  1.64 Mbits/sec
[  3] 16.0-18.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3] 18.0-20.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3] 20.0-22.0 sec   400 KBytes  1.64 Mbits/sec
[  3] 22.0-24.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3] 24.0-26.0 sec   400 KBytes  1.64 Mbits/sec
[  3] 26.0-28.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3] 28.0-30.0 sec   400 KBytes  1.64 Mbits/sec
[  3] 30.0-32.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3] 32.0-34.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3] 34.0-36.0 sec   200 KBytes   819 Kbits/sec
[  3] 36.0-38.0 sec   200 KBytes   819 Kbits/sec
[  3] 38.0-40.0 sec   200 KBytes   819 Kbits/sec
[  3] 40.0-42.0 sec   400 KBytes  1.64 Mbits/sec
[  3] 42.0-44.0 sec   400 KBytes  1.64 Mbits/sec
[  3] 44.0-46.0 sec   200 KBytes   819 Kbits/sec
[  3] 46.0-48.0 sec   300 KBytes  1.23 Mbits/sec
[  3] 48.0-50.0 sec   200 KBytes   819 Kbits/sec
[  3]  0.0-50.9 sec  7.81 MBytes  1.29 Mbits/sec
```

Thus, my `iperf` test shows that my Linux laptop is pulling much more slowly than my Windows laptop (which is pulling precisely the rate promised by my ISP for the plan I have).

Additionally, I set up a `lighttpd` web server on the same university Linux computer and attempted to download a several-gigabyte file using the following command:

```
$ aria2c -x 16 -s 20 http://XX.XX.XX.XX/testfile.tar
```

Using 8 concurrent connections --- I don't know why just 8, but I doubt that's relevant to this problem --- `aria2c` was able to download at approximately 1 Mbit/s also.

**How can I investigate why my Linux laptop is downloading so slowly?**

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but sometimes my Linux laptop when connecting to the wireless network will use device `eth1`, and other times it will use device `eth2`.  This doesn't make sense to me because there's only 1 wireless device (I assume) on my laptop; it's a standard Dell laptop.

**[Below are details on some of the hardware in my Linux laptop.]**

Wireless interface:

```
        description: Wireless interface
        product: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY
        vendor: Broadcom Corporation
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
        logical name: eth2
        version: 01
        serial: 00:25:56:b2:16:3e
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
        configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) ip=192.168.1.69 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
        resources: irq:17 memory:f1ffc000-f1ffffff
```

System:

```
description: Portable Computer
    product: Latitude E6500 ()
    vendor: Winbond Electronics
    serial: obe
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=portable uuid=44454C4C-0000-1000-8000-80C04F6F6265
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       vendor: Winbond Electronics
       physical id: 0
       serial: .obe    .              .
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Winbond Electronics
          physical id: 0
          version: A24
          date: 08/19/2010
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1664KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot
```

Comment: Odd, I thought the wireless nic's are recognised as wl0. Anyway, that's my machine

Comment: I thought so too.  They were under my previous laptop (from linuxcertified.com, not from Dell) running Ubuntu 11.10.  Like I said, sometimes it's `eth1`, and sometimes it's `eth2`.  That, alone, doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The only idea I can think of is to ensure it's connecting via 802.11g and not b. If you can force your WiFi to only support g that might help isolate.